# Google play game services sign in code display black overlay and just gone

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

Working with Android Studio, 
I added implementation google play services - game 15.0.1 version code on my gradle...
and write android developer site's sample codes into my app.. (https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart)

but I cannot show any google play game dialog.
when I start that sign in code, my app  displays  a black splash screen during about .5 seconds and gone...

I added internet permission but the problem still there
how can I fix i'm very sad.

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: oh i found the problem. google play game services works fine, it just do not display any dialog something likes logging in.. or...  thanks for answering